# How to sum up entire column of a table values in django website?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am very new to programming. I want to sum up my entire column payment_amount. I don't know which code should I use to sum up entire column and save it on home server. I have tried to create a function but it didn't work. Can I use multiple function on same page or will have to write all different function in same def function()? I will be very grateful for your kind help.

**HTML part:** I

```
<h1>Hellow</h1>

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

Payment Completed


<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Mobile</th>
    <th>Payment</th>
  </tr>
  {% for payment in payments %}
    <tr><td>{{ payment.payee_name }}</td><td>{{ payment.phone_number }}</td><td>{{ payment.payment_amount }}</td></tr>
  {% endfor %}
  {% for totalpayment in totalpayments  %}
     <tr>
       <td>{{ Payment.totaldonation }}</td>
     </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>


{% endblock %}
```

**admin.py part:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import ToDo, Payment
class PaymentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('payee_name', 'phone_number', 'payment_amount')

admin.site.register(Payment, PaymentAdmin)

**forms.py part:**

from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import ToDo, Payment

class PaymentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Payment
        fields = ['payee_name', 'phone_number', 'payment_amount']
```

**models.py part:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class Payment(models.Model):
    payee_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    payment_amount = models.IntegerField()

    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py part:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from .forms import ToDoForm, PaymentForm
from .models import ToDo, Payment
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.db.models import Sum

@login_required
def payment(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'builderpage/payment.html', {'form':PaymentForm()})

    else:
         try:
             form = PaymentForm(request.POST)
             newpayment = form.save(commit=False)
             newpayment.user = request.user
             newpayment.save()
             return redirect('completedpayment')
         except ValueError:
             return render(request, 'builderpage/payment.html', {'form':PaymentForm(),'error':'Bad Data Pressed In'})

@login_required
def completedpayment(request):
        payments = Payment.objects.filter(payee_name=request.user)
        return render(request, 'dashboards/paymentcompleted.html', {'payments':payments})

def totaldonation(request):
    data = Payment.objects.aggregate(Sum('payment_amount'))
    return render(request, 'dashboards/index.html', {'data':data})


@login_required
def viewpaymentown(request, payment_pk):
    payment = get_object_or_404(Payment, pk=payment_pk, name=request.user)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = PaymentForm(instance=payment)
        return render(request, 'dashboards/payment.html', {'payment':payment, 'form':form})
    else:
        try:
            form = PaymentForm(request.POST, instance=payment)
            form.save()
            return redirect('completedpayment')
        except ValueError:
            return render(request, 'dashboards/paymentcompleted.html', {'payment':payment, 'form':'form', 'error':'Bad Data. Try again.'})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a python for loop, to sum up the entire column and show it on the dashboard.

```
def totaldonation(request):
    data = Payment.objects.all()
    total_sum = 0
    for item in data:
        total_sum += item.payment_amount

    return render(request, 'dashboards/index.html', {'sum':total_sum})
```

This will sum all the values that are in the payment_amount of each item in the payment model.

Comment: It is not giving any result

Comment: I had to use pandas and it became super easy. Thanks for taking time to answer it. I am grateful for your help.